# Eclipse doesn't strike out deprecated classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Here is a sample code

```
public class DeprecatedTest {

    private final List<Object> instances;

    public DeprecatedTest(){
         instances = new ArrayList<Object>();
         instances.add(new Depr());
         instances.add(new Depr1());
         instances.add(new Depr2());
         instances.add(new Depr3());

         Depr depr = new Depr();
         Depr2 depr2 = new Depr2();
     }  

    @Deprecated
    public class Depr{}
    @Deprecated
    public class Depr1{}
    @Deprecated
    public class Depr2{}
    @Deprecated
    public class Depr3{}    
}
```

Eclipse does strikes out class name before instance name (2 last declarations). But if it is anonymous class Eclipse doesn't strike out class initialization after new operand. It's really inconvenient! Is it configurable?

---

> SpringSource Tool Suite  Version:
>   2.5.0.M3 Build Id: 201008251000

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334978

Answer (score 3):

Should be very easy ->

- open Preferences
- type "deprecated" in the Search Box
- go to Java->Editor->Syntax Coloring
- find Java->Deprecated members in the Tree
- Check the Enable Checkbox and the Strikethroigh Checkbox

tadaa!

Comment: instances.add(new Depr());
         instances.add(new Depr1());
         instances.add(new Depr2());
         instances.add(new Depr3());  - will not be stroked out. That is the problem. If all these deprecated classes will be in another place, I won't ever now that I add ti instances deprecated anonymous classes!!!!!!